# Is it correct to change Heroku's PostgreSQL password using psql's \password command?

Tags: heroku

On Heroku, apparently it is possible to use psql's `\password` command to change a password.  Is this something that is "correct"? or do you *have to* use the rotate credentials facility documented here?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials#pg-credentials-rotate

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use `pg:credentials:rotate`? That's documented, it's known to work... why wouldn't you use it? My biggest concern is that bypassing that command may prevent the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable / `pg:credentials:url` command from providing accurate credentials.

Comment: yes, we do not have the privileges to do that (at least not from the web UI).  Someone published the DB user credential on an email (like: sigh...), and we wanted to contain the situation asap (everyone on the email thread has access, so, it is not a big deal, but email is not a secure channel).  We changed it using \password, which worked, and now are coordinating to do the proper credentials "rotation", but then I wondered: is it wrong to just use \password on Heroku?  I was unable to find an answer on Heroku's documentation.

Comment: Since you have already changed the password this way, I suggest you check the `DATABASE_URL` and / or output of `pg:credentials:url` to see if they reflect the new (current) password. If they do, great. Likely no issues. If not, then there's a problem: since Heroku can change the credentials at any time you should always connect via one of those methods. And if they don't currently work with the password you set that way...

Comment: If you can confirm whether the new password is reflected correctly I can add a proper answer.